# Is the completion of $(k[x,y]/f)_\mathfrak{m}$ isomorphic to $k[[x]][y]/f$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, power-series

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $f\in k[x,y]$ be an irreducible polynomial with no constant term that is not a polynomial in $x$ alone.

Is it the case that the completion of the localization of $k[x,y]/(f)$ at the maximal ideal $(x,y)$ is isomorphic to $k[[x]][y]/(f)$?

If so, is there an easy proof? If not, an easy counterexample?

If it is true in less than full generality, what additional hypotheses are needed?

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect this to be true. The completion of $(k[x,y]/(f))_m$ is local, but $k[[x]][y]/(f)$ need not be

Comment: @user115654 - the case I had in mind was $f=y^2-x^3+x$, in which case $k[[x]][y]/(f)$ embeds in a power series ring $k[[t]]$ by $x\mapsto t^2$, $y\mapsto t(1+t^2/2-\dots)(1-t^2/2-\dots)$, and I though this might be an isomorphism. But you're right. In fact, in general it does not seem to me that $f$ should even be expected to be irreducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't true, and there are easy counterexamples.

As user115654 points out in the comments, $k[[x]][y]/(f)$ may not be local. This happens if $f$ has zeros on the $y$-axis other than $(0,0)$. For example, take $f = x^2 + y^2-y$. Then $(x,y)$ and $(x,y-1)$ are both maximal ideals of $k[[x]][y]/(f)$.

Comment: Just a note: the completion of a domain need not be a domain: your first example $(k[x,y]/(y^2 - x^2 + x^3))_m$ is actually the canonical example of this! The factorization of $f$ in $k[[x]][y]$ also gives a factorization in $k[[x, y]]$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit the answer to reflect this. Wait, is the completion of $k[x,y]/f$ at $(x,y)$ equal to $k[[x,y]]/f$?

Comment: Indeed it is: if $(R,m)$ is a Noetherian local ring, and $I$ is an $R$-ideal, then $\widehat{(R/I)} \cong \widehat{R}/I\widehat{R}$. Also, for more information about when the completion is a domain, you can look up analytic irreducibility